# Need to clear out multiple databases before each test using PHPUnit & DbUnit

Tags: phpunit, dbunit

I am writing tests for our system that does joins across multiple databases.  I chose to use MySQL for my test databases, i.e. test_database1 and test_database2 which I create by dumping my production schemas into the respective tables.  Note that I don't need any data at this point, only the schemas.

What is the best way for me to get these databases cleared out before I run a test?  I have two requirements:

1. There are some foreign key constraints which prevents me from just being able to TRUNCATE, so I need each table cleared out "manually".
2. I need both databases cleared out.

I looked into overriding:

```
class PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Truncate implements PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_IDatabaseOperation
```

in DbUnit but it seems to rely on the DataSet contents which in my case will be empty since I preload my schema via mysqldump --no-data.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a utility function that rebuilds the database which can be called before tests which require a clean database or in you setUp() function:

```
class DbUtil {

    public static function rebuild($src, $dest) {
        exec("mysql -u someuser -p password -e 'DROP DATABASE $dest'");
        exec("mysql -u someuser -p password -e 'CREATE DATABASE $dest'");
        exec("mysqldump -d -u someuser -p password $src > mysql -u someuser -p password $dest");
    }
}

class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected function setUp() {
        DbUtil::rebuild('prod_database1', 'test_database1');
        DbUtil::rebuild('prod_database2', 'test_database2');
    }

    // ...
}
```

This may not be the most performant approach but you will get a clean database for every test.

If you are willing or can to switch from MySQL for your tests, I have had success building an template sqlite database file and copying that file to a different location for testing.  Each test just overwrites the test database file with the clean template file.

Note: Exec command are written for demonstration purposes only and have not been tested for exact switches/parameters.

Comment: when running this command the terminal will prompt for the password at each time. Is there a way to avoid that too?

Comment: You'll need to replace the strings `someuser` and `password` in the commands above with the credentials for a user that has appropriate prileges to DROP and CREATE databases.

Comment: Yes already did that, It didn't work. each time I had to re-enter my password.

Comment: does it prompt you for you password 4 times everytime the rebuild method is called?

Answer (score 0):

I do it using standard PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase with fixtures

```
protected $_connectionMock;
protected $_secondDbConnectionMock;

protected $backupGlobalsBlacklist = array('application');  // btw this hack will speed up your tests

/**
 * @return Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Db_Connection
 */
protected function getConnection()
{
    if ($this->_connectionMock == null) {
        $multiDb = Zend_Registry::get('multidb');

        $connection = $multiDb->getDb();

        $this->_connectionMock = $this->createZendDbConnection(
            $connection, ''
        );

        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($connection);
    }
    return $this->_connectionMock;
}

protected function getSecondDbConnection()
{
    if ($this->_dnsConnectionMock == null) {
        $multiDb = Zend_Registry::get('multidb');

        $connection = $multiDb->getDb('second_db');

        $this->_secondDbConnectionMock = $this->createZendDbConnection(
            $connection, ''
        );
    }

    return $this->_dnsConnectionMock;
}

protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->databaseTester = NULL;

    $this->getDatabaseTester()->setSetUpOperation($this->getSetUpOperation());
    $this->getDatabaseTester()->setDataSet($this->getDataSet());
    $this->getDatabaseTester()->onSetUp();

    $secondDataSet = $this->getDataSetForSecondDb();
    if ($dnsDataSet) {
        // create data set for second db
        $secondDataTester = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DefaultTester($this->getSecondDbConnection());
        $secondDataTester->setSetUpOperation($this->getSetUpOperation());
        $secondDataTester->setDataSet($secondDataSet);
        $secondDataTester->onSetUp();
    }

}

protected function getDataSetForSecondDb()
{
    return null;
}
```

}

but I extended it in order use multidb